# Bulk get auto post "Subtitle" from "Excerpt" field content

Tags: wordpress, function, subtitle

I have a blog with more than 10.000 posts.
What I need is to generate a **subtitle** for all my posts, taking that text from the content on each post´s **excerpt** field. As the image example I include on this post.

[get subtitle from excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcedV.png)
I would like to request for help finding the ideal functions.php code.

**my_subtitle($article)**

**get_the_excerpt()**

Or maybe if someone can guide me with a phpmyadmin SQL to bulk update these fields on my existing posts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can "brute force it" with `get_posts` and a `foreach` loop:

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // will grab all
    'post_status' => ['publish', 'draft']
]);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // get post id from $post object
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    // get the excerpt
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post_id);

    // there is no "sub title" function in WordPress so we can save it as postmeta
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_sub_title', $excerpt);
}
```